# jQuery - como alterar texto depois de elemento "<i>"?

Tags: jquery, html5

Segue código:

```
<div class="file-caption-name">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file kv-caption-icon"></i>
    Alterar texto aqui
</div>
```

Já tentei dessa forma:

```
$('div.file-caption-name i').text('your new title');
```

O resultado fica assim:

```
<div class="file-caption-name">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file kv-caption-icon">your new title</i>
    Alterar texto aqui
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer mover o texto da `div` para o `i`?

Comment: Não, apenas mudar o texto "Alterar texto aqui" para "your new title".

Comment: Não mude a preferência da sua resposta favorita, mas note que a minha não mexe em nada no seu HTML. Abs!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para alterar o texto **depois** e não o texto todo do `.file-caption-name.` você pode fazer de duas maneiras, adicionar um elemento inline span:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#trocar", function () {
    $(".file-caption-name > span").text("Olá, mundo!");
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="file-caption-name">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file kv-caption-icon"></i>
    <span>Alterar texto aqui</span>
</div>

<button id="trocar">Trocar</button>
```

Ou você pode pegar o `<i>` e desanexar usando o [**`detach()`**](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) ele e então remover o conteúdo e adicionar novamente o `<i>`:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#trocar", function () {
    var icon = $(".file-caption-name i").detach();
    $(".file-caption-name").text("Foo, Bar!");
    icon.prependTo(".file-caption-name");
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="file-caption-name">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file kv-caption-icon"></i>
    Alterar texto aqui
</div>

<button id="trocar">Trocar</button>
```

Comment: Nice bro, resolveu aqui.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda obrigado por aceitar!

Answer (score 6):

**RESPOSTA ATUALIZADA.**

Você pode fazer um tratamento para pegar apenas o TEXTO dentro da `div` com `nodeType == 3` e fazer um `replace` com `textContent` eliminando espaços em branco antes e depois do texto com `$.trim()`:

```
 $('div.file-caption-name').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace($.trim($('div.file-caption-name').text()),'your new title');
});
```

```js
$('div.file-caption-name').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace($.trim($('div.file-caption-name').text()),'your new title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="file-caption-name">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file kv-caption-icon"></i>
    Alterar texto aqui
</div>
```

Comment: Isto não esta alterando o texto depois do elemento, ele esta alterando o conteúdo inteiro do elemento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Verdade. Já atualizei a resposta.